# Using eventbrite api gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, eventbrite

I'm trying to build an app around information from the eventbrite API. I stumbled upon this unofficial eventbrite gem (https://github.com/therabidbanana/eventbrite) but can't figure out what the usage terms mean:

```
require 'eventbrite'
Eventbrite.setup("APP_KEY")
user = Eventbrite::User.new("USER_KEY") #=> <Eventbrite::User >
user.venues #=> [<Eventbrite::Venue>,...] # Venues the user has defined
```

I've included the gem in my gemfile, run bundle install, but can't figure out how to pull a user's events.

Anyone willing to help me out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

therabidbanana has released a very full-featured gem, but I'm not sure if he is currently maintaining or supporting it.

I would recommend contacting him (via GitHub) with questions, or taking a look at Eventbrite's official gem: 
https://github.com/ryanjarvinen/eventbrite-client.rb

More information regarding open-source code related to Eventbrite is available on their GitHub page: http://eventbrite.github.com

Feel free to contact Eventbrite's developer relations team if you have additional questions:
http://developer.eventbrite.com/contact-us